# Karma test run with Jasmine cannot find TypeScript module

Tags: typescript, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner, commonjs

I want to test my [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) code with [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) executed by [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/).

Unfortunately the Karma is unable to find my module and exists with "Module name has not been loaded yet for context".

My TypeScript class is this:

**src/ts/Greeter.ts**

```
export default class Greeter {
  name:string;

  constructor(message:string) {
    this.name = message;
  }

  greet() {
    return "Hi " + this.name;
  }
}
```

**dest/js/Greeter.js**

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        this.name = message;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hi " + this.name;
    };
    return Greeter;
}());
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = Greeter;

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

And here is my test file:

**test/ts/GreeterSpec.ts**

```
///<reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts"/>
import Greeter from "../../../src/ts/Greeter/Greeter";

describe('Greeter', function () {
  it('says Hi', function () {
    var name = 'Joe';
    var greeter = new Greeter(name);
    expect(greeter.greet()).toBe('Hi ' + name);
  });
});
```

**test/js/GreeterSpec.js**

```
"use strict";
///<reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts"/>
var Greeter_1 = require("../../../src/ts/Greeter/Greeter");
describe('Greeter', function() {
  it('says Hi', function() {
    var name = 'Joe';
    var greeter = new Greeter_1.default(name);
    expect(greeter.greet()).toBe('Hi ' + name);
  });
});
```

When executing my test, I get this response:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "../../../src/ts/Greeter/Greeter" has not
>   been loaded yet for context.

This is my compiler configuration:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sortOutput": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

How should I declare my import in my test specification to make the compiled version finding my module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hesitate to post this since I don't use TypeScript, but shouldn't the file **test/js/GreeterSpec.js** where you have the `src/ts/Greeter/...`

```
"use strict";
///<reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts"/>
var Greeter_1 = require("../../../src/ts/Greeter/Greeter");
```

instead be `src/js/Greeter/...` as in:

```
"use strict";
///<reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts"/>
var Greeter_1 = require("../../../src/js/Greeter/Greeter");
```

In other words, it looks like you are calling the TypeScript when you really want the JavaScript.

Comment: Good catch! Looks like the TypeScript compilation of my test files messes this up! I will have a look at this and change it to what's needed. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with TypeScript but when I look at the generated JavaScript code, I see code that *cannot* work with RequireJS. The reason you are getting the error you are getting is because of this code in `GreeterSpec.js`:

```
"use strict";
///<reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts"/>
var Greeter_1 = require("../../../src/ts/Greeter/Greeter");
```

This cannot work because the form of `require` that takes a single parameter *must* appear inside a `define` to be safe to execute:

```
define(function (require) {
    var Greeter_1 = require("../../../src/ts/Greeter/Greeter");
```

I also see that `Greeter.js` does not call `define` so RequireJS will have a problem resolving `require("../../../src/ts/Greeter/Greeter")`. (In general a `shim` in your RequireJS configuration *could* help but I think with the specific code you have it a) it would not help and b) it is not necessary.)

I see in your compilation configuration you have `"module": "commonjs"`. The problematic code is in fact good CommonJS code. However, RequireJS wants to load AMD modules, and I [see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) that `"module": "amd"` is a possible value, so I would switch to this.